# AlertDialog box containing spinner and edittext returning a nullpointer when called

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a dialog  box that works perfectly well when i use just the spinner, but returns a null pointer when i try to fetch a value from an edit Text to be used for calculation in the OK button.

below is my deliberations for your consideration

```
//the alert box
public boolean dialogValuessP1() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Arena.this);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Connecting Options");

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.option, null);


        EditText connectionNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtConnectedBy);
        connectedV = Integer.parseInt(connectionNumber.getText().toString());


        spinnercategory = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.viewSpin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.category, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnercategory.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnercategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ConnectBY = spinnercategory.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Connect",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                        if (ConnectBY == "Single Score") {
                            scoreV =  1 * connectedV;
                        } else if (ConnectBY == "Double Score") {
                            scoreV =  2 * connectedV;
                        } else if (ConnectBY == "Tripple Score") {
                            scoreV =  3 * connectedV;
                        }

                        alert = true;

                    }

                });



        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        // cancel the alert box and put a Toast to the user

                        dialog.cancel();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please choose Connection Pattern",

                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Arena.this.finish(); used to close the game
                        alert = false;

                    }

                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show(); 
        return alert;

    }
```

//the option.xml is the Xml file used

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/viewSpin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@array/category" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/connectwith" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtConnectedBy"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the edittext is inside the alert dialog 
try using

```
EditText connectionNumber =(EditText) dialogView .findViewById(R.id.txtConnectedBy);
```

and to retrive the value use

```
String edittextValue=connectionNumber.getText().toString()
```

I think you can achieve this functionality with a custom dialog functionality

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CustomDialog.this);
                // Include dialog.xml file
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                // Set dialog title
                dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

                // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
                EdittText text = (EdittText ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);

                Spinner spinimage = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                //spinner details here 

                dialog.show();

                Button ok= (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

                ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Close dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        String text = text.getText().toString();
                         //do something with the edittext value
                    }
                });
```

please make a try and share your view

Comment: with this, it does not allow to be inflated

Comment: please try a custom dialog to achieve this functionality may be that will be more easier

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, i made the following changes to the code and was able to use both an edittext and a spinner in the same alertdialog

```
public boolean dialogValuessP1() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Connecting Options");

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.option, null);

    final EditText input = (EditText) dialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtConnectedBy);

    spinnercategory = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.viewSpin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.category, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnercategory.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnercategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            position = arg2 + 1;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Connect",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    edittextValue = input.getText().toString();

                    connectedV = Integer.parseInt(edittextValue);
                    scoreV = position * connectedV;
                    playNext();
                    alert = true;

                }

            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    // cancel the alert box and put a Toast to the user

                    dialog.cancel();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "It is not your turn to Play",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    alert = false;

                }

            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    alertDialog.show();
    return true;

}
```